# Beginner: checking parameters and integers

Tags: javascript, parameters, integer

So this is the question:
Code a function called daySuffix that takes a single parameter. The parameter is checked to ensure it’s a number (see Number.isNaN() and then converted to the nearest integer. A check is made that the integer is in the range 1 to 31 inclusive. If either of the checks fail return the value null. Finally the integer should be returned with the appropriate day of the month suffix (e.g., “1st”, “2nd”, “3rd”, “27th”, etc.). Use only one further return statement (for a total of three)

```
var daySuffix = function() {
    var num1 = 100;

    if (typeof num1 == 'number') {
        document.write(num1 + " is a number <br/>");
    } else {
        document.write(num1 + " is not a number <br/>");
    }

    function between(daySuffix, min, max) {
        return daySuffix >= min && daySuffix <= max;
    }
    if (between(daySuffix, 1, 31)) {

    };

    console.log()
};

daySuffix()
```

Obviously i'm a little lost. Can anyone give me a hint as to where to go from here?

Comment: Where are you exactly lost? Consider relooking at this: `function between(daySuffix, min, max)`. I'd give another variable name for the first param. Then when you make the call `between(daySuffix, 1, 31)`, first param should be `num1`

Comment: I think you need to pass num1 as parameter and return the result.. Or make you question more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
//function with a parameter
var daySuffix = function (num1) {
    if (isNaN(num1)) {
       //not a number, return null
       return null;
    }

    if (num1 < 1 || num1 > 31) {
        //outside range
        return null;
    }

    //logic for finding suffix
}

console.log(daySuffix(0));     //null
console.log(daySuffix(1));     //"1st"
console.log(daySuffix("hi"));  //null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample:

```
var daySuffix = function (num) {
    var result = null,
        days = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "st"];

    if (!isNaN(num)) {
        num = Math.round(num);
        if (num >= 1 && num <= 31) {
            result = num + days[num - 1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that may work for you:

```
var daySuffix = function(num) {
    var stringEquivalent, last2Digits, lastDigit;
    var suffixes = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th'];
    var roundedNum = Math.round(num);

    // Check to see if `num` is a number and between the values of 1 and 31
    if (typeof num === 'number' && roundedNum >= 1 && roundedNum <= 31) {

        // Convert to string equivalent
        stringEquivalent = String(roundedNum);

        // Get the last 2 characters of string and convert them to number
        last2Digits = Number(stringEquivalent.slice(-2));

        lastDigit = Number(stringEquivalent.slice(-1));

        switch (last2Digits) {

            // 11, 12, and 13 have unique 'th' suffixes
            case 11:
            case 12:
            case 13:
                return roundedNum + 'th';
            default:
                return roundedNum + suffixes[Math.min(lastDigit, 4)];
        }
    }

    // Null is returned if the 'if' statement fails
    return null;
};
// Test results
for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) { console.log(daySuffix(i)); }
```